# Where does Ramban discuss OCD and the mikvah?

Tags: sources-mekorot, medicine, mikvah-ritual-bath, psych-mentalhealth

I was told that the [Ramban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahmanides) writes regarding women who have awful problems using the mikvah because they keep worrying they're not clean enough -- in today's terms, we call that obsessive-compulsive disorder.

Can anyone help me locate this Ramban, please?

Comment: Re "they keep worrying they're not clean enough -- in today's terms, we call that obsessive-compulsive disorder": not everyone with OCD will necessarily do that, and not everyone who does that necessarily has OCD. (+1, though.)

Answer (score 10):

Likely you are thinking about the Ramban's conclusion to his Hilchot Niddah ([9:25](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49095&st=&pgnum=316)):

> ומדיני החציצה לא טוב היות האדם מחמיר יותר מדאי ומחפש אחר הספיקות לפסול טבילתה בדבר הקל, כי אם כן אין לדבר סוף, אלא אחר שחפפה ראשה וסרקה במסרק וחפפה ורחצה כל גופה בחמין ונזהרה לבלתי תגע בשום דבר חוצץ ותעשה טבילתה בפשיטות איבריה וכל גופה, לא יכניס אדם ראשו בספיקות החמורות אשר אין להן קץ וסוף, כגון עצמה עיניה ביותר קרצה שפתותיה ביותר ומשאר הספיקות, כי מי יוכל להבחין בין עצמה ביותר ובין לא עצמה ביותר.‏
>   And the laws of Chatzitza: It is not good for a person to be too strict, looking into doubts to invalidate an immersion for a light matter, for there is no end to the matter. Rather, after she has cleansed her hair, combed it, washed and cleansed her whole body in hot water, and she was careful to not touch anything which might cause a Chatzitza, and she immerses her entire uncontorted body [into the Mikva], one should not stick his head into these strict doubts which have no end or conclusion (such as if she closed her eyes or lips too tightly, or other doubts), for who is able to truly discern between [closing them] too tightly and not too tightly? (my translation)